# Matrix Loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do a simple for matrix loop in R. But for some reason it is not working. Any help would be great! Here is what I have:

```
        t<-length(gdat2)
        > t
        [1] 6848
        for (i in 2:t)

        {F1[i,]=F1[i-1,]}

       > F1
     [,1]     [,2]
     [1,] 7.494972 17.04625
```

Where F1 is a 1x2 matrix.

EDIT: Okay. I changed it. Thanks all for the responses! And I edited my code to read 'i' instead of 't'...I found out that I do not have a broken keyboard :).

So, what I have is a F1 matrix with the first row written. NOW, I want to create a new matrix where all the subsequent rows (rows 2 and onward) will be written based on the F1 matrix. I should have 6848 rows in the new matrix.
For instance, row 2 should read: 7.494972  17.04625
              row 3 should read: 7.494972  17.04625
              ....
              row 6848 should read: 7.494972  17.04625
 Hope this clears everything up.

Comment: What is with the letter `t`? All others keys are broken on your keyboard?

Comment: So basically what you want is to take the first row of F1 and copy it 6848 times below it...? Btw don't skip a line between the for(...) and the actual code that is to be looped on, it's not helping readability.

Comment: If you convert your matrix to a dataframe, your code should work.

Comment: Hey guys, so I edited my initial question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really just want to copy the first line of the matrix 6848 times, this code will do the work:

```
for (i in 2:t){
F1<-rbind(F1, F1[i-1,])
}
```

Comment: thanks maRtin for the response. However, that loop gives me a length of 13696, not 6848...

Comment: if you apply the function length(F1) you get 13696.
length() here returns the number of cells of the matrix, since you have 6848 rows and 2 columns, you get 6848 * 2 = 13696 cells.
If you want to check the number of rows of your matrix use nrow(F1). 
If you found my answer useful, please give me an upvote. thx